# Play sound in local notification

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I have used Local Notification in my app an successfully generated an alert at correct time..

But when i tried following code for playing sound it does not play....

localNot.soundName =@"Ghulam Ali-Chamkte Chaad Ko.mp3";

Can anyone tell me the reason....Does the playing  length of sound file affects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6), you need to use "aiff", "caf" or "wav" files.

The link provided shows some ways of converting audio to these formats on your mac.

Comment: +1--Format matters.. and size also affects...it should be less than 30 sec...what i have found